# How to extract only the second cell of the second column of a html table using PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping, html-table

I'm trying to extract only the second cell of the second column of a html table using php.
This is an example of the table:

```
<table border="1" bordercolor="#FFCC00" style="background-color:#FFFFCC" width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Marcos</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>1234 west 34 st</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td>2013336666</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>fax</td>
    <td>201456789</td>
</tr>
```

I just want to pull the cell with the address.

Comment: So how do you plan to go about doing this?

Comment: I try using simple_html_dom.php but I only can pull the table or a column I have no idea hoe to pull just one cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend you use the PHP DOMDocument class which is much more full-featured and well-supported. I also use DOMXPath for easy traversal.

```
$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTML($your_html_string);
$dom_xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$value_you_want = $dom_xpath->evaluate('string(/table/tr[2]/td[2])');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you didn't state how you plan to do this, I'll just throw something out there. Try the PHP DOM found here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

It's a great OOP approach to reading and manipulating an XML or HTML DOM in PHP.

Comment: Sorry I'm new with php I try to use simple_html_dom.php and  I can pull the table or a column but I just need only one cell.